# Keybinding ALT+C doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, system, key-bindings

I've got some keybindings like

```
new KeyBinding() { CommandParameter = %param%, Key = %key%, Modifiers = ModifierKeys.ALT  CommandTarget = %content frame%, Command = NavigationCommands.GoToPage });
```

If I use for example `%key% = Key.H` it's work as expected. Only for `Key.C` it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

p.s. after clicking <kbd>ALT</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd> windows system sound is played

Comment: Could it be a conflict? Do you know if Alt+C is already used for something?

Comment: i guess it could be a conflict

Comment: but i don't know how to check it